# vim replace multiple lines by a variable (in register)

Tags: vim, replace

I am using Vim and I have `${HOME}` saved on a register, which is the fastest way of replacing those `../../..` by `${HOME}` ?

```
LDFLAG = -L../../../libs
         -L../../../libs
```

result

```
LDFLAG = -L${HOME}/libs
         -L${HOME}/libs
```

Comment: `:%s#../../..#${HOME}#`-> `:h :s`; `man sed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `${HOME}` in, let sey `"u`, then press `ctrl+v`, selected `../../../` , then press `s`, then `ctrl+R` (a `"` should appear) and the letter of your register (`u` in our example).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your cursor is on the first `.` of `../../../` and your text is stored in register `a`…

### With visual-block selection

1. Press `<C-v>` to enter visual-block mode,
2. extend the selection horizontally to the last `/` of `../../../`,
3. extend the selection vertically,
4. press `"ap` to put from register `a`.

### With a repetition

1. Press `v` to enter visual mode,
2. extend the selection horizontally to the last `/` of `../../../`,
3. press `"ap` to put from register `a`,
4. move the cursor to the next `../../../`,
5. press `.` to repeat.

### With a substitution

1. Do `:,+s@\.\./\{3}@<C-r>e<CR>`

Comment: Hi romaini ! thank you for your editing ! the visual selection do not work for me, it only replace the first line.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what "I have `${HOME}` saved on a register" means but the simplest solution would be

```
:%s#\M../../..#${HOME}#
```

It's replacing all of the `../../..` with `${HOME}`, or if you really using a register (say `@a`), then you can use `\=@a` instead of `${HOME}` to replace the match with the contents of register `a`.

#### Explanation

- `:`: Open command prompt
- `%`: On the whole buffer...
- `s`: ...replace ([substitute](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#:substitute)) the match...
- `\M`: ...of a [non-magic pattern](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5Cm) (e.g. a literal string)
- `#`: Used sharp instead of mostly used slash (`/`) as separator, because the pattern contains slash

Comment: hi bimias ! that works great ! to be saved on a register for me is to, for example, select ``${HOME}`` in visual mode and do ``" h y`` (register ``h``)

Comment: OK, I just though you're new in Vim world, this is why I wondered on using registers.